# How to use Fourier transform to solve Fisher-Kolmogorov?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

How can I use Fourier Transform to solve Fisher-Kolmogorov Equation in 1D?

\begin{equation}
u_t(x,t) = u_{xx}(t) + u(1-u)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
u(0,x) = \phi(x)
\end{equation}

with Dirichlet 
\begin{equation}
u(0,t)=0 \\
u(1,t)=0
\end{equation}

and Neumann boundary conditions
\begin{equation}
u_x(0,t)=0\\
u_x(1,t)=0
\end{equation}

The problem was partially solved following [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yVQj.gif) tutorial.

Solving the equation 
\begin{equation}
u_t = u_{xx} \\
\end{equation}

from $t$ to $\Delta t$ gives

\begin{equation}
\hat{u}_t = (ik)^2 \hat{u} \\
\tilde{u}(x,t+\Delta t) = F^{-1} \left\{e^{-k^2 \Delta t} \hat{u} \right\} 
\end{equation}

Now solving the equation

\begin{equation}
u_t = u \, (1-u) \\
\end{equation}

Using the splitting operator method we can write

\begin{equation}
u(x,t+\Delta t) = e^{-u(1-u)\Delta t} \tilde{u}(x,t+\Delta t)
\end{equation}

which gives the solution

[image: Solution]

I need to know:

How can I impose Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions?

Comment: the non-linear term leads to frequency doubling. Which leads to instabilities.

Comment: Thanks, I tried implementing a solver and like you said it's unstable. What kind of instability are you talking about? Could you provide a good reference?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94473/solving-the-heat-equation-with-fourier-transformations?rq=1) may help.

Comment: @Mattos thanks I saw that but in that case $g(x,t)$ in this case $g(u)$